# Wordpress migration to a new developed webpage

Tags: wordpress

Case:

A old website developed with wordpress and run for serveral years.

Now, this wordpress website is giveup and will be re-developed to a new website which is not using wordpress anymore.

Old data i.e. article content, uploaded image file, members' info etc will be migrated to the new website.

Question: 

1. Is it any tools for this type of migration?

2. If there is no tool for data transfer and I need to export the content from mysql, where can I get the article content in database?

3. Where can I find the uploaded file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data migration is always dependant on two things.
1. If your current framework/CMS can export the data you have, and
2. If the new framework/CMS can import data that you have just exported.

Since both frameworks are different, i.e. WordPress to any other CMS, your new CMS must be able to map the exported XML files. Which means, it must be able to customize the import process to tell what bits of data is Title, Content, Categories etc.

To answer your questions

1. Is it any tools for this type of migration?
   Since you didn't mention what you new framework is, no one can really suggest a tool. Just google for "WordPress to YOUR-NEW-FRAMEWORK migraiton" and you'll get a number of tools. If the new framework is a custom PHP framework then I think you'll have to import the data manually or code an import script for it.
2. WordPress has a pretty good export tool. Check [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen) to learn how to export WordPress content.
3. Where can I find the uploaded file?
   The uploaded files are referenced in the exported XML file, so at the time of import anywhere else, they can be fetched and downloaded if you can. Otherwise, you can find them in the `uploads` directory located at `YOUR-SITE-ROOT/wp-content/uploads/`

**UPDATE:**
As you are not targetting any framework/CMS but want to show the data with custom PHP, I'd suggest two methods.

1. Use the current database that WordPress is using and build your PHP script around it, benefiting from `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` tables.
2. A better way to go with this is using the [WP REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/). This way, you keep the WordPress installation as is and still use it's data in your custom PHP site. Advantage of this method is that you won't have to bug your mind with scripting around database structures you have less information of.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I do not use any framework/CMS, and just want to show the contents with a normal php page and mysql. Therefore, I just want to export data from wordpress and import to my newly re-designed database, and also want to find the uploaded file and move them to my new folder path!

Comment: @AlphaWong Check the Update.

Comment: Thank you for the updating info, unfortunately, since the server hosting service of old wordpress website will be end soon and will change to another service provider, wordpress is not willing to use anymore that I will not try to migrate wordpress from one server to anothere server! Therefore, re-develop a website is preferred and just get the data is ok.